# Determine Largest Files In a Windows Sharepoint Services Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss

Is there any way to determine which files stored in my site collection that are the largest?  I would like to identify them somehow and then delete them to free up some space.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [site data query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx) to find all documents that are bigger than a certain size:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
// restrict to document libraries
query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"101\" />";
query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"File_x0020_Size\" />";    
query.RowLimit = 20;
query.Query = "<Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\"File_x0020_Size\" /><Value Type=\"Number\">{size in bytes}</Value></Geq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"File_x0020_Size\" Ascending=\"FALSE\" /></OrderBy>";

DataTable bigFiles = web.GetSiteData(query);
```

**Query in readable:**

```
<Where>
  <Geq>
    <FieldRef Name="File_x0020_Size" />
    <Value Type="Number">{size in bytes}</Value>
  </Geq>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name="File_x0020_Size" Ascending="FALSE" />
</OrderBy>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use SharePoint API and iterate through all items in all lists in all sites in your site collection.